# Way to omit MySQL column count on insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a large dump of custom CMS's news section into WordPress. Unfortunalety, columns doesn't match. Some of them - yeah, sure - like title, date or content. But WordPress required a lot of columns which this dump doesn't have. Is there a way to either omit this count on insert or filling it with dummy (preferably blank) data? Search and replace (even with regular expressions) won't do here, since it is really huge file and simple 'find' takes a lot of time.

Comment: You can specify the column names that you are inserting into: `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)`

Comment: I know this syntax. My problem is - I have literally hundrets of thousants of lines (my IDE keeps hanging when I have this file opened) and adding in every line another blank col is not possible.

Comment: I never used anything like this and I don't have any time to learn it now (it has to be done by tomorrow and I got this table two hours ago).

Comment: You upload the table as a 'staging table', then do a `INSERT ... SELECT` into your main table, selecting only the fields you want. There, you have now learned what a staging table is.

Comment: Does every row in your dump have the same columns?

Comment: @njk - how do I upload it like that? Is it possible in PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you were given a "table." If it included a schema, create the table and insert the data. Otherwise, create the table based on the data columns and insert your data. This is considered your staging table. You can now write a `SELECT` statement to select the data from your staging table that will be inserted into your destination table. You will finally prepend an `INSERT` statement to insert your selected data. It should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable (fruits, animals, numbers, plants)
SELECT fruits, animals, numbers, '' FROM stagingTable
```

If you did not have `plants` in your staging table, you would simply `SELECT ''` or `SELECT NULL` for that column. You can then simply drop your staging table.

Comment: @tomek-buszewski If you provide me the 6 columns that you have, I can prepare a better `INSERT` statement for `wp_posts`.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the answer to my clarification is yes, you can insert multiple rows by delimiting them with a column.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) 
VALUES (row1val1, row1val2),
(row2val1,row2val2)
```

Comment: I proposed this in the first comment and it seems the OP cannot use this solution.

Comment: your comment makes no reference to inserting multiple rows, I think OP may think he has to fire a separate insert statement for every row.

Comment: Given that the OP stated "Unfortunalety, columns doesn't match," I don't think that your solution would resolve non-matched columns.

Comment: Sorry invertedSpear, but your solution isn't helpful. I have a large file with, let's say, 6 columns. And I need to insert it to WordPress wp_posts which has a lot more cols. Problem is - how to fill those missing columns automatically.

Comment: does the DB not have default values for those missing columns? if not change your schema to give them default values, then if the insert statement doesn't specify that column, it will just be entered with it's default. If you don't have defaults, you are going to have the same issue using a staging table.

Comment: @njk, how would using a staging table deal with non-matched columns any better than inserting multiple rows? Either solution depends on columns in the destination table having valid default values.

Comment: @njk, I will give you that your solution will deal with a badly designed table that would allow for empty strings and nulls (or other row to row static value), but not have them be the default value. If the design was done right, then that static value would be the default, in which case the insert/select, or multiple insert would not even need to mention that column.

Comment: @invertedSpear I agree that we probably wouldn't have to deal with this if the table had been designed better, however it's a unique situation that requires a unique solution.

Comment: If the OP has the ability to edit the table, I would disagree with that statement. The level of effort to properly set the defaults is pretty minimal, and will make future situations such as this easier to deal with. S/he could save a lot of future aggravation by taking care of it now. If OP doesn't have the ability to edit the table, well, then it doesn't really matter what anyone's opinion on the design is.